Failed to 'open' on 'serial port' error
I am trying to load wled onto an esp32 but I am getting an error that says "failed to open serial port". I believe I have the device installed correctly, when I plug it in it pops up in the list as "cp2102 USB to UART bridge controller" but I keep getting the error. I am super new to linux, any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Does this answer your question? Serial port terminal > Cannot open /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied

sudo setserial -v -g /dev/ttyS0
